# Converting and Formatting Time Zones

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I am dealing with my worst nightmare - timezones and DST. I already read a lot of posts on stackoverflow but I still cannot figure it out. Here is the problem:
I am making an API request for what needs to be a UTC one day of data but the system I work with needs a request in a US/Pacific time. The documentation says:

- Time zone is supported for report range filtering, but all responses are returned in US Pacific time zone please adjust Daylight Savings Time end accordingly.
- API calls after DST starts should have -07:00 appended and after DST ends should have -08:00 appended
- 2018 Daylight Savings Time starts on Sunday March 11th 2018 at 2 AM.

  - API calls prior to March 11th should have the following syntax: `&start=2017-03-10T00:00:00-08:00&end=2017-03-10T23:59:59-08:00`
  - API call for the actual day of Daylight Savings should have the following syntax: `&start=2018-03-11T00:00:00-08:00&end=2017-03-11T23:59:59-07:00`

Apart from the confusing 2017 and 2018 mixture, there is  no actual parameter to specify the time zone you need but you have to adjust the data that is in the following format : `2018-03-11T00:00:00-08:00`.

To me it looks like a ISO format but I spent quite some time trying to get `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` and not `'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'` and couldn't make this work. So I created the following workaround:

```
def dst_calc(single_date):
    zone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
    day = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    tdelta_1 = datetime.strptime('2:00:00', '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime('1:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
    tdelta_0 = datetime.strptime('1:00:00', '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime('1:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')

    logger.info('check for DST')
    if zone.localize(datetime(single_date.year, single_date.month, single_date.day)).dst() == tdelta_1:
        logger.info('summertime')
        start = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00-07:00"
        end = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T23:59:59-07:00"
    elif zone.localize(datetime(single_date.year, single_date.month, single_date.day) + timedelta(days=1)).dst() == tdelta_1:
        logger.info('beginning of summertime')
        start = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00-08:00"
        end = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T23:59:59-07:00"
    elif zone.localize(datetime(single_date.year, single_date.month, single_date.day)).dst() == tdelta_0:
        logger.info('wintertime')
        start = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00-08:00"
        end = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T23:59:59-08:00"
```

Obviously this is only in US/Pacific timezone and to get the UTC day I need to subtract 8h difference from the start and 8 timestamp i.e. have `T16:00:00-08:00` but I am wondering if there is a better way / package / formatter that can do this is a more logic-proof way.

Comment: Doesn't the `datetime` package do most of this for you?

Comment: `datetime` does in fact handle a lot of this. Even better, the `pytz` package is going to be a friend here, and `pendulum` will probably become your soul mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime's `astimezone` method to determine the correct hours.

```py
import datetime, pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now() # datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 17, 0, 0, 0)

now.astimezone(pytz.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 16, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```